# Make client listen all the time instead of listen only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mqtt

I have a mqtt client running on angularjs and node.js mqtt module. There is a simple switch which will publish topics on a mqtt broker whenever the switch status change.

The relevant html code looks like this;

```
<div ng-controller="SwitchCtrl">
    <md-switch ng-model="switch_status.sw1" aria-label="SwitchCtrl" ng-change="onChange(switch_status.sw1)">
        Wireless Light Switch: {{ switch_status.sw1 }}
    </md-switch>
</div>
```

Here is the angularjs controller;

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('SwitchCtrl', ['$scope', 
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.switch_status = {
                sw1: true,
            };

            var mqtt_client = mqtt.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
            mqtt_client.subscribe('hello/world');
            mqtt_client.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("MQTT connected");
            });

            mqtt_client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
                console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
                mqtt_client.end();
            });

            $scope.onChange = function (sw_state) {
                if (sw_state === true) {
                    mqtt_client.publish('hello/world', 'switch on');
                }
                else if (sw_state === false) {
                    mqtt_client.publish('hello/world', 'switch off');
                }
            }
        }])
;
```

My problem is that the controller code only runs once. I want this code segment in the controller to keep running forever so that client is aware of new messages being published on subscribed topic.

```
        mqtt_client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
            console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
            mqtt_client.end();
        });
```

How to make the mqtt client listen all the time instead of listen only once?

Comment: why do you `mqtt_client.end();` in your listener? keep it alive and you will get all the notifications (I'd assume, not familiar with that)

Comment: Upvoted your commend even though you make me I feel like a damn fool :( Please provide it as an answer. It is the right answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Comment away the line that ends the mqtt_client connection. That will work! Credit goes to one of the commenters floribon who provided the answer in his comment first.

```
mqtt_client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
            console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
            //mqtt_client.end();
        });
```